# Generating a sinusoid sound signal in Java

Tags: java, performance, floating-point, audio, signal-processing

Is there any legroom left for optimization (without switching to C)?

```
static byte[] generateSound(double frequency, int sampleRate, int samples) {
    byte output[] = new byte[2 * samples];

    int idx = 0;

    double _tone = 2 * Math.PI / (sampleRate / frequency);

    for (int i = 0; i < samples; ++i) {
        double dVal = Math.sin(_tone * i);

        final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));

        output[idx++] = (byte) (val & 0x00ff);
        output[idx++] = (byte) ((val & 0xff00) >>> 8);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably good room for performance gain regarding the Math.sin call itself. You could easily create a [lookup-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934267/3500521) - there's no faster way than just taking the values straight from an array. (The link's benchmark measures a factor ~6 speed difference.)

It may be problematic because it may cause audible distortions, but that would depend on how much memory you're willing to invest in the lookup-table. Also, you could invest a few more cycles by obtaining *both* array entries addressed by (_tone*i) and then adding them up, both multiplied by 0.x and respectively (1-0.x), effectively fading over between values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much it will optimize it but this:

```
double dVal = Math.sin(_tone * i);
```

Shouldn't be needed.

Replace:

```
final short val = (short) ((dVal * 32767));
```

With:

```
final short val = (short) ((Math.sin(_tone * i) * 32767));
```

The compiler may be able to optimize it well enough that this doesn't matter, but it may help.

Answer (score 0):

A few optimisation:

- Using bitwise operators

  ```
  byte output[] = new byte[samples << 1];
  double _tone = (Math.PI << 1) / (sampleRate / frequency);

  final short val = (short) ((dVal<<15) - dVal);
  ```
- Reducing variables

  ```
  short val = (short) ((Math.sin(_tone * i) * 32767));
  ```
- Why final? Not sure if adds to the overhead.